# How to change style based on componen tag name in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a `<app-teams-list>` component which has `<app-team-thumbnail>` component as a child. I want to change the background color of the child element based on selector name. I have done the following but nothing has happened.

//team-list.component.html

```
<h2>Teams</h2>
<app-team-thumbnail
  *ngFor="let team of mergedTeams$ | async"
  [teamId]="team.id"
></app-team-thumbnail>
```

//teams-list.component.scss

```css
app-team-thumbnail {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Are we not able to change the style base on selector name ?

Comment: And why u dont change the css you want, in the style.css of the `app-team-thumbnail` component? I am not sure if you can do what you want.

Comment: @tufonas I have already thought that but how can I achieve that in this way?

Comment: I have tried in the past even with a css class but still doesnt work. I think u cant do this.

Comment: Is it because that selectors are not real html tags ?

Comment: They definitely are, but you should check the width/height of the elements inside the browser using dev tools. You may need to set `width: 100%` or `height: 100%` before you notice anything.

Comment: Yea @MikeS. is right, you can do this. I made a quick test just to test that css works. For some reason css in general works but doesnt work for containers. I set width and height at 200px with some background-color but doesnt work.

Comment: @CelalettinTurgut In `app-team-thumbnail` component, do you use any div or any container?

Comment: @tufonas In `<app-team-thumbnail>` I have `<mat-card></mat-card>` as container. Do you mine that I should use this container for my style purposes?

Comment: If you set your `mat-card` background-color to inherit your code above will work!